# Class or interface expected error (java)

Tags: java

When i try to compile this:

```
    public static int compareCardhl (Card c1, Card c2) 
}
if (c1.suit > c2.suit) return 1 ; 
if (c1.suit < c2.suit) return -1 ; 
if (c1.rank > c2.rank) return 1 ; 
if (c1.rank < c2.rank) return -1 ;  
return 0; 
}
```

i get a lot of class or intereface expected errors. They all point at the `if's`. i also get a `; expected` error at the end of `Card c2)`.

whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

on line 2 the bracket is wrong it should be {

Comment: Any decent code editor might help you with features such as code block folding (aka outlining) and bracket matching: if a block can't be folded, or folding it behaves wrongly (too many or too few lines are hidden), something's wrong with the block's brackets. Placing the caret on either of the brackets (opener or closer) should highlight its corresponding pair.

Answer (score 1):

A slight suggestion if I may, it is probably better for what you are trying to do that your Card class implements the Comparator interface

```
public interface Comparator<T> { 
   public int compare(T t1, T t2); 
}
```

Comment: why should i use the Comparator interface?

Comment: Hi David,
The Comparator interface will give you out of the box ordering on all collections that support it. The definition of the comparator is:
"Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second."

It looks like you're trying to accomplish the same thing, so no need to re-invent the wheel. It will also make use of your API more intuitive as you're using a known interface.

Hope that's clear, if not please let me know.